# Wordpress.org pages refresh when logging out of Gmail

Tags: passwords, xss, google, wordpress

I've noticed that when I change my Gmail account by logging out of one account and then logging into another, all open [Wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/) pages refresh. Additionally, when I recently changed a password on a Google account, in my Wordpress.org tab [Lastpass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lastpass-password-manager/) asked if it should store the new password.

What is the connection between Wordpress.org, or any other arbitrary page, and Google? I notice that the Wordpress.org pages use Google Analytics and have a Google Plus link in the HTML:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-href="https://plus.google.com/+WordPress"></div>
```

Is that the cause of the refresh and password prompt? **Is this something that I as a user should be concerned about?**

Comment: Not related to your problem, but Google allow its users to be logged on different accounts at the same time, so you won't have to logout from the first one when you want to check the second one's mails. Use [this form](https://accounts.google.com/AddSession) to add another account to your current session (it won't link your accounts for other sessions or mix their data).

Comment: @BenoitEsnard: Thank you Benoit. There are reasons that I would rather not log into both accounts at the same time. Often I will simply use another browser, depending on what I need at the time.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **no.**

Wordpress has quite a few community-developed plugins that integrate features from Google services onto Wordpress sites that can be found in their "Plugin Directory". [Examples from a search for the keyword "Google" on the Plugin Directory.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=google)

Since these plugins are not officially developed by Google, odds are that not all of them use the most aesthetic/efficient code. Sounds like that particular plugin has the page refreshing if the session detects a google login change, so that Wordpress can receive the new Google information from your browsing session, which would inform the site/plugin of a new user/no user for the +1 button, adsense info, etc. to associate with.